# Maximum concurrent users in a powerapp

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas

What is the most concurrent users in a powerapp app (using SharePoint lists)? My concern is performance, the user not having to wait because of multiple users.

Answer (score 2):

The [performance consideration blog](https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/performance-considerations-with-powerapps/) says:

> Limits
>
> When deploying your app to a large number of user, one has to keep in mind the connectors are throttled. PowerApps currently support 600 requests per minute per user and up to 30 concurrent calls per user.

This is explained clearly in [community forum](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/600-requests-per-minute-per-user-limit/m-p/157187#M53042) as below:

> the 600 limit is defined per-user per-minute, there is no limits on the number of users using the app.